# .htaccess redirect from subdirectory to another domains subdirectory accordingly

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a redirect from my primary domain to an secondary domain, but only if the primary domain's request is to a sub directory.

The sub directory I want to redirect from is FTP, so if the user makes the following request:

http://www.site1.com/FTP/free/50b694124bd63/SaMple+PicTure.PnG

it would be transformed to

http://www.site2.com/FTP/free/50b694124bd63/SaMple+PicTure.PnG

but if the user makes a request that does not involve the FTP folder, the user will not be redirected. Like so:

http://www.site1.com or http://www.site1.com/somethingelse/

**I am, however; a bit lost when it comes to making .htaccess files**. What I have tried to do so far is:

```
# Redirect users
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ftp(.*)$ http://site2.com/FTP/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Any directions or samples would be great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the rewrite engine for simple redirects.  I think you just want to use the Redirect directive:

```
Redirect /FTP http://www.site2.com/FTP
```

By default, this will result in a "temporary" redirect response (HTTP status 302).  If you're sure the URL of the second site will never change, you can cause a "permanent" redirect response (HTTP status 301) by adding the `permanent` argument:

```
Redirect permanent /FTP http://www.site2.com/FTP
```

Also, note that the path of URLs is case-sensitive.  If you want http://www.site1.com/ftp to also redirect, you will either need to add a rule with the lowercase path,

```
Redirect /ftp http://www.site2.com/FTP
```

or use mod_speling.